# Monitor windows messages using a system-wide hook

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, dllexport

I'm coding a windows monitor that needs to be notified whenever a window is created/closed/focused.

I'm trying to do a system-wide hook placed in a DLL (with `SetWindowsHookEx`), but i'm not very confident, since I never practiced exporting DLL's.

How should I intercept the `WM_CREATE`, `WM_CLOSE` and `WM_SETFOCUS` messages of other windows, and notify to the monitor application about those messages, along with the handle (HWND) of their destination? (a code example would be good)

I'm using C++ with VS2003. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add the `winapi` tag to increase chances of getting an answer.

Comment: This is too broad.  Look at the CBT hooks instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Don't use CreateWindowsHookEx(), far too difficult to do correctly, especially on a 64-bit OS.  Use the built-in support for programs that help users with disabilities, the accessibility api.  SetWinEventHook() is the easiest to get going, covers the operations you quoted.  The built-in support for UI Automation is built on top of it, gives more options to tinker with the window itself.